# Align a button to the right inside a navbar leaving a margin to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for styling a website and everything works right for the login form, which is located inside a navbar:

[image]

As you can see, the button has a nice margin to the right. Well, I want to achieve the same with my logout button, but I don't know how without recurring to my own CSS code:

[image]

I think there's a way to achieve the same right margin of the login button for the logout one using Bootstrap. Here's the code that creates the logout button:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <span class="navbar-brand">@Model.User.UserName's profile</span>
        <a class="btn navbar-btn btn-danger navbar-right" role="button" href="@Url.Action("UserLogout", "Login")">Logout</a>
    </nav>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: can you please share live link or demo where you are facing this issue as by only html we can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a bootstrap only solution, you could wrap your `span` and `a` (button) into an additional `container`

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <span class="navbar-brand">@Model.User.UserName's profile</span>
    <a class="btn navbar-btn btn-danger navbar-right pull-right" role="button" href="#">Logout</a>
</div>
</nav>  
...
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19422/)

Comment: I added only the button to a container as you said and it worked. Do you know why a container is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the class `.pull-right`, then add a `margin-right: ??px;` to the same class in your own css stylesheet (This has to be loaded after the Bootstrap.css)

So the `a` Tag would look like this:

```
<a class="btn navbar-btn btn-danger navbar-right" role="button" href="@Url.Action("UserLogout", "Login")">Logout</a>
```